# How to spawn a bash script from Java on Windows?

Tags: java, cygwin

Is there a way to make Java spawn a bash script on Windows?  I have cygwin installed, and I've associated the .sh file extension with cygwin bash.  The following code, which works on Linux, isn't working:

```
 String[] cmdArray = { "scriptName.sh", "-force", categoryName};
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray, null, directory);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding either bash or start as the first parameter.

Comment: I had to provide the full path to "bash.exe" to get it to work.  Well, sort of, it's not working yet, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to provide the executable itself in order to do this. The Process.exec method only seems to execute exe files.